# How to download live stream that consists out of separate .ts and .aac segments?

Tags: ffmpeg

There is a m3u8 file with only the containing links to video segments and a different one with only the audio segments. Because it is a live streaming I have to start downloading both video and audio streams at the same time.
When just writing "ffmpeg input output" for video and the same command for audio in the following line, the program is trying to download the video file "until the end" before starting the audio stream -- which does naturally not work since the live stream is indefinite.